# Compound JS load configuration from DB on startup

Tags: compoundjs

I'm trying to use Compound JS and want to load on startup some values from DB and store them in global variables shared across all sessions.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to put them in the `config/initializers` folder.

Example: `/config/initializers/settings.js`

```
module.exports = function (compound) {
    compound.models.Setting.all(function (err, settings) {
        compound.settings = settings;
    });
};
```